# ASP.Net MVC:When form submit then textbox value pass as querystring instead of route data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

When form submit then textbox value pass as querystring instead of route data

i am showing data in tabular format and i have textbox where user will enter something to send to action method. textbox data is passing as querystring instead of route data.

see my form submit code and routing code.

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("PageWithSort", new { page = ViewBag.CurrentPage, SortColumn = ViewBag.CurrentSort, CurrentSort = ViewBag.OldSort, SearchText = ViewBag.SearchText },FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="row form-gap">
        <div class="input-group col-xs-5 col-lg-4">
            @Html.TextBox("SearchText", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-search btn-info" id="submit">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    <span class="label-icon">Search</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group col-xs-5 col-lg-8">
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

### my routing code

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "edit",
        url: "Customers/Edit/{page}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Edit" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "details",
        url: "Customers/Details/{page}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Details" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "delete",
        url: "Customers/Delete/{page}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Delete" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "PageWithSort",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{SortColumn}/{CurrentSort}/{SearchText}",
        defaults: new { action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional, SortColumn = UrlParameter.Optional, CurrentSort = UrlParameter.Optional, SearchText = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

i am not posting my full code because that big. see i use `Html.BeginRouteForm("PageWithSort"` where i mention route name and also passing route values. when i write something in textbox and click submit then url in browser address bar looks like **http://localhost:55831/Customers/Index/1/CompanyName/CompanyName?SearchText=ana**

but i want url with search data should look like **http://localhost:55831/Customers/Index/1/CompanyName/CompanyName/ana**

my ui looks like [image]

please tell me what i need to add or change in my routing code or razor code to change the url from http://localhost:55831/Customers/Index/1/CompanyName/CompanyName?SearchText=ana to http://localhost:55831/Customers/Index/1/CompanyName/CompanyName/ana

any help or idea would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Because its a `FormMethod.Get` (a browser has no knowledge of your routes, and the values of form controls are always added as a query string)

Comment: @StephenMuecke sure i will change from Get to POST and let you know. thank you sir.